# Spellcheck for pdf files

Tags: pdf, spell-checking

Is there any utility or command on Ubuntu for checking spelling errors in a pdf file? Or a way to integrate spellcheck in Evince?

Answer (score 17):

You can use LibreOffice to import and edit PDF files. Note, however, LibreOffice PDF import support is still prone to errors, due to the complexity of the PDF format.

You may also try using Inkscape to edit your PDF document, which may have better results with some files, provided that the required fonts are installed. Make sure that spell checking is enabled in Edit > Preferences:

[image]

Then, go to Text > Spellcheck to open the spell checking dialog

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me where I can download pdf-import extenion for LibreOffice. I have tried google search, but unable to get any link.

Comment: @kkp: it's in the software center.

Comment: @kkp if the answer answered the question you can mark it as solved by clicking the tick button.

Comment: I am testing the options. When I imported a pdf file in LibreOffice, some words are combined such as "theperformance" and therefore showing several spelling errors.

Comment: Abiword also distorts while importing: some pairs of words are combined into a single word, and math notation is imported as combinations of letters and symbols, e.g. Fv for $F_v$.

Comment: @SanderHeinsalu have you tried with an up to date copy of LibreOffice? Try opening the file in Draw.

Comment: Still important question and answer: While pdfimport meanwhile seems to have been integrated in LIbreOffice main, it still distorts at lot, e.g. ligatures are ignored/skipped, leading to loads of typos. But, nevertheless, a reasonable option. Thanks.